# How do I begin playing DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

DLC in the first game was handled by having quests automatically added to the quest log. After downloading Captain Scarlett, I continued my existing game and found that I didn't have any new quests in either my first or second playthrough.

How do you begin the Captain Scarlett DLC, or any of the other DLC?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You start the DLC by using the Fast Travel system to go to the first area of the DLC.  From there, you'll receive a new mission and further instructions.  These are the areas you're looking for:

- **Captain Scarlett and Her Pirate's Booty:** Oasis
- **Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage:** Badass Crater of Badassitude
- **Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt:** Hunter's Grotto
- **Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep**: Unassuming Docks

Note that you may be restricted from playing DLC by your level and/or story progression.

Answer (score 13):

I thought DLC in the first game was handled by opening new fast-travel locations - you received the quest when travelling to them. I would assume it is the same for Borderlands 2.

Comment: It's the same here.

Comment: I suppose you're right. "Oasis" is now a fast travel target. Thanks for jogging my memory!

Comment: I think you also have to be level 15 for it to apear

Comment: @BenBrocka I could fast travel to Oasis at lvl 11. The Quest you receive is marked at lvl 15 though

Comment: @Josefvz you're correct, you can go to it at any time actually. But the first quest is at least level 15 and enemies are scaled to at least that level (some will be below level 15 but the average is at least 15).

Comment: @BenBrocka weirdly enough, I can fast travel to any of those locations at the start of the game.Can anyome explain this to me?

Comment: @AdibHawari - So long as the DLC is activated you can fast travel there. What Ben is saying is that - should you travel there at a low level - all the enemies will be very hard because they start around level 15.