# How do I start the Torgue DLC quests

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I begin playing DLC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89315/how-do-i-begin-playing-dlc)

I have loaded up my Level 50 character who has completed the main campaign on both difficulties and beat the first DLC on the harder mode.  I do not see any new quest markers to start the Torgue quests.  Steam says I have the DLC and I see it in the DLC option of the game itself. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @galacticninja Good call - I have voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new location on the fast travel grid, the **Badass Crater of Badassitude**. Once you arrive there, you will be shown an intro cutscene and given a quest to begin the DLC.

Comment: @Haphazard - Bonus tip: In the past, and, presumably, the future, all DLC shows up as a new fast travel location.