# How do I start the dlc?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I begin playing DLC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89315/how-do-i-begin-playing-dlc)

I saw that you have to fast travel to get the quests, but I don't have the locations on my fast travel list?

I'm level 18 so it shouldn't really matter, but I'm stuck.

Comment: In case you maybe didn't know the name, all DLC fast travel locations are Oasis, Hayter's Folly, Magnys Lighthouse, The Rustyards, Washburne Refinery, Wurmwater, Badass Crater of Badassitude, Badass Crater Bar, The Beatdown, Southern Speedway, and The Torgue Forge. Check your list carefully for those names.

Comment: Also, are you playing on PC or console? Do you have a legal copy of the game that only you are using? If you are gamesharing or using an illegal copy DLC might not work.

Comment: Have you gotten to Sanctuary? Does the DLC show up as purchased in the menu (at least on PC there's a menu to confirm your DLC)

Comment: The starting locations for the DLC are Oasis (DLC#1), Badass Crater of Badassitude (DLC#2) and the most recent Hunter's Grotto (DLC#3).

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the DLC installed.  Assuming you own the game on Steam, verify the game properties, and head to the DLC tab.  It will show what DLC content you have installed.

Second, go to any Fast Travel station.  You should be able to fast travel to the DLC once you're in the correct level range.

- Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty - levels 15 to 30.
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage - levels 15 to 30.
- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt - levels 30 to 35.